# Multiple Tap Gestures in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have several tap gestures being created and recognized on different UIViews from in my TableViewController and the different gestures are being recognized correctly. As seen in this code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
  let tapOnView1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
  let tapOnView2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
  cell.View1.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnView1)
  cell.View1.userInteractionEnabled = true
  cell.View2.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnView1)
  cell.View2.userInteractionEnabled = true
  return cell
}
```

My Handle tap looks like this:

```
func handleTap(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tappedView = sender.view
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()

        if tappedView == cell.View1 {
            print("View 1 Tapped")
        } else if tappedView == cell.View2 {
            print("View 2 Tapped")
        }
}
```

I wanted to move all this code to my CustomCell UITableViewCell class as there are actually several more UIViews that have different actions that need to be taken on a tap. Additionally moving them all to the Cell itself seems to me to be the right thing to do. I searched for answers but the only true answer I have seen is to use buttons and there are several reasons that this is really not an option for me without some serious refactoring and rewriting. I have tried several iterations to the following code in my CustomCell class:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        let tapOnView1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
        addGestureRecognizer(tapOnView1)

        let tapOnView2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
        addGestureRecognizer(tapOnView2)

    }
```

and this handleTap function:

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if delegate != nil && item != nil {
            if sender.view == view1 {
                print("view1 tapped")
            } else {
                print("view2 tapped")
            }
        }

    }
```

The tap for view1 is never called. It only ever calls the view2 tap no matter where in the cell I tap. I have tried using different Selector functions (i.e. handleTapOne: for View1, and handleTapTwo: for View2) but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Again it works in my UITableViewController but it does not work when I try to move all of the tap recognizers to the UITableViewCell.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your code in `override func awakeFromNib()` looks wrong, should it be `self.View1.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnView1)` ?

Comment: Well I am a bit of an idiot. Thanks. That did fix my issue. I was going insane and something as silly as that was holding me up. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

iphonic answered my question above. I was an idiot I guess. staring at a problem for two long and missing the most simplest of things.